# posting serialized data with jquery ajax in IE6 not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

when i post some data with jquery ajax command in ie6 and i

> print_r($_POST)

php print an empty array..

i can alert this data with alert function in ie by adding this line of code:

> alert(form_data)

how can i post submited data to php?i dont know where the problem is in ie6?
this is my code for posting data

```
$('#submit').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = $(this).attr("name") + "=submit";
        var form_data = $('#create_album_form').serialize() + "&" + post;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "create_album.php",
            data: form_data
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $('#album_data').html('');
            $('#album_data').html(data);
            $('#album_data').delay(1000).trigger('reveal:close');
            if(data == '<div class="success">آلبوم شما با موفقیت ساخته شد</div>'){
                $('#myalbums').load('update_albums.php').fadeIn('500');
            }

        });


    });
```

Comment: I believe you should do ```data: { v : form_data }``` and then ```parse_str($_POST['v'], $v); var_dump($v)```

Comment: It is strongly recommended by Microsoft to not use IE6 anymore. What is the error? can you add HTTP sniffing to see what the issue is? Also can you tell us which jQuery version you use?, Live is deprecated for .on but jQuery 2 is not compatible with IE<10

Comment: jquery version is 1.9.1 and i just optimising my code to be usable in all browsers

Comment: .live is no longer in 1.9.1 - use .on as I suggested

Comment: could you do `console.log(post)` or `console.dir(post)` before the ajax part?

Comment: @mplungjan - correction to your comment above: jQuery v2 is for *IE9* or higher.

Comment: @ianace - this is IE6; it has no built-in console. (Firebug Lite may help though)

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is removed in jquery 1.9.x use `.on()` instead